# React native start scroll after animation

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, animation, scrollview

Experts, I'm new in react native and I would like to ask if the animation of native ios ScrollView header is achievable in react native

I want Scrollview to start scroll after header animation end,
if there is a way or idea to animate the header before scroll start

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOZXd.jpg

I hope I explained my idea well, thanks

Comment: hello ahmed i did something similar , and it is applicable to what you need

Comment: @AmirDoreh could u mention that please ?

Comment: you need to add an event to your scrollview and when it is scrolled you will animate your view's style, in this example i am changing the opacity which for you it will be the height of your view.   https://imgur.com/rtNpTgI.

Comment: Yes, it's almost the same but in your example, animation and scrolling at the same time making the scroll speed a little bit accelerated in the beginning, my point is it possible to pause the scroll start until animation end, thanks @AmirDoreh

Comment: that is totally customizable , you can disable your scroll till the view expand . you are free to do them , and the rest is the same

Comment: so the view expands depending on what ? if the scrolling disabled already!! view animate with scroll event? and the scroll event is calling when the scroll starts!! Am I using animation event wrong ? I'm adding the event to `onScroll={}` prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved with onScroll event listener, to animate UI